# How to convert Gradle build of Android Studio project to Maven project?

Tags: android, maven-2, android-gradle-plugin

I have a `Gradle project` using `Android studio`, I need to convert this build to `Maven build Structure` as per some requirement, is it a mammoth task to convert the Studio project to Maven or can be done with easy steps.

I have been looking on the internet for the same but not been successful.

Any inputs on the same would be of great help.
Thanks.

Comment: I dont understand exactly what you are trying to do as you can create Maven artifacts on Android studio , is that what you want to do? There is a maven plugin available for Android Studio. If  you install that plugin you will be able to execute all maven commands on your project(mvn package) to generate required pom files and wars. http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7179?pr=idea

Comment: let me give it a go, and will update you here back after its done.I just wanted to convert my Gradle build to the Maven build, thats about it

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the size of the project, if you only have 1 phone app and a couple of dependencies it should not take to long.

As for how you do it I can't say too much. I've done the opposite and that was from reading the Gradle docs. But if you know both build systems it should not be hard. If you don't then learn both so you can understand what you are doing.

Comment: So, there are no automatic conversion tools available to do the same transformation?